# Laravel jobs being processed but not doing anything

Tags: laravel, laravel-jobs

I have checked multiple answers regarding this issue but didn't seem to have a proper solution. I'm firing a job, and it's working well in `sync` mode, but not working at all in `database` driver.

queue.php

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),
```

.env

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

How i'm firing the job. I tried removing `onConnection('database')` but it would run on `sync` driver instead

```
SendNotifications::dispatch(array("message" => "test"))->onConnection('database');
```

I'm executing the following command to listen

```
php artisan queue:work database
```

When I'm firing the job, it gets written in the `jobs` table, after a few seconds, it gets `processed`. The problem is: It's not firing. If I remove the `onConnection('database')` it works on `sync` mode without any issues.

```
class SendNotifications implements ShouldQueue {

 public function __construct(){
 }

public function handle(){
   // here i'm connecting to a notifications api
 }

}
```

Example of what's inside `handle()`

```
if($this->event_name === "example"){
            $room = $this->getRoomByID($example_id_variable); // database_call
            if(empty($room) === true) {
              return;
            }
            $notify_receivers = getBlabla(); //get the receivers from the database (complex query)
            if(empty($notify_receivers) === false){
              foreach($notify_receivers as $receiver){
                $this->sendMessageAPI($receiver, $this->payload);
              }
            }
          }
```

sentMessageAPI

```
public function sendMessageAPI($id, $payload) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    $post_fields = array(
        "key" => "key",
        "secret" => "secret",
        "channelId" => $id,
        "message" => $payload
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.piesocket.com/api/publish",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_fields),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
}
```

I'm running this on a localhost using xampp. Any ideas why it's not actually firing? I've checking the `payload` column in the database table `jobs` and it's correct.

Comment: It's possible that something within your `SendNotifications` code just does not work outside of the web context so would only work on the sync queue driver. It would help to provide with what's actually happening in `SendNotifications` if not the actual code then an example code that reproduces the code without exposing any logic that can't be exposed

Comment: Example code is included. Please check it out.

Comment: I'm trying to log and it's working. Nevertheless, the actual code isn't being executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll want to use `QUEUE_CONNECTION` not `QUEUE_DRIVER` in your `.env` file. That should remove the need for `onConnection('database')` and make the database your default. If you want to force a single job to run sync, you can use `dispatch_now`.

Can you expand on "not firing"? You said it gets processed after a few seconds, so is the job not being picked up at all or just isn't functioning as intended? Does the job go into the `failed_jobs` table?

Another important thing to note, you **must** restart your queue workers if you change the `SendNotifications` job class in your example. Workers do not necessarily re-read the class and may be using an older or incorrect class. For local testing I'd recommend either `queue:listen` or explore the `--once` argument. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#the-queue-work-command

Comment: I used `QUEUE_CONNECTION`, the job doesn't inserted  in `database` mode. Also, using `onConnection('database')` and `php artisan queue:listen` doesn't process the jobs. Let's say I use `onConnection('database')` and `php artisan queue:work database` then the job gets processed. It gets cleared from `jobs` table and don't get added to `failed_jobs`. Also, it gets processed, but the actual code of the job doesn't get executed. I've tried logging and creating an error, it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, using `php artisan queue:listen database` process the jobs. Nevertheless, it doesn't get executed.

Comment: I can describe the issue by saying that `handle()` method isn't being called.

Comment: I'll provide bounty to this answer as it gave the first and right step. The actual issue was with the cURL code getting rejected for SSL. Basically, the code was working well, the connection with the `QUEUE_CONNECTION` needed to be fixed.